# execute("Select... NOT returning item that exists

Tags: python, ms-access

I have a kivy app that uses the `.execute("Select` command to do a query for an item from our Access database.
The issue is that not all matching records that are `LIKE` what the user searched for get displayed.

My query code is:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT `PART CODE`, PROGRAM, MATERIAL\
                       FROM PROGRAMS_DATABASE\
                       WHERE `PART CODE` LIKE ? or PROGRAM LIKE ?",
                       (('%{}%'.format(search_string)),
                        ('%{}%'.format(search_string))))
```

After the query I use a for loop to enter the results into a dictionary.

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    # populate dictionary here
    # then send it for kivy to display
```

My program connects to the database and runs great however, A certain entry does not show up even though I know it is there and matches the search string.
If we know the `PROGRAM` value to look for, it has no problem finding it and displaying it.

If for example, the user searches for *ABCDE123* and the records have 4 variations with the string ending in something like *-R-A, -R-B, -R-C, -R-D*
The query will return the first two and last one but not the 3rd record.
If we know that the 3rd record's `PROGRAM` value is and use that in the search string, the query will return the 3rd record that it was leaving out before.

I would love to give you more of my python code but it is a large application and some info in it is proprietary.
My suspicions are in how I query the data. I am connecting to our Access database using the AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 that allows for non MS products to communicate with MS products.
In my code, I use the pypyobdc to connect to the database

Is it known to be problematic to communicate with a database this way or am I 
doing the querying wrong?

I hope the info I provided is enough for you to grasp my concept.

Comment: Try use [] instead '' to delimit names that have spaces or special characters. Even better, don't use spaces and punctuation/special characters (underscore is only exception) in naming convention. Also advise not to use all upper case just because it is harder to read. Camel case is better: `PartCode` or `Part_Code`. Is the \ a line continuation character? Possibly you need opening and closing quote marks as well as string concatenation character on each line before the \.

Comment: In Access query, the wildcard criteria would be: `"WHERE [PART CODE] LIKE '*'"` Text parameters use apostrophe delimiters.

Comment: In Python use triple-quotes for strings that span multiple lines.

Comment: I am tapping into an existing database. Changing the column labels will break other dependencies that is why the space and caps. I will try some of the suggestions mentioned. @June7 yes the `\\` is a line continuation. Ill post back if the modifications work

Comment: I did some experimenting, turns out that the record I was searching for had two entries with identical values in the `PART CODE` column. This effectively caused the query to filter out the duplicate. This being said, the material is different for the two entries. How can I modify my query to keep the same search criteria but include duplicate valued rows found in the `PART CODE` column?